# Active menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the fallow code to set active menu with jquery:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          var url = (window.location.href).split("/").pop();
          $('.menu-sidebar a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
       });
   </script>
```

And the HTML it works for:

```
 <nav class="menu-sidebar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="about" title="About">About us</a></li>
     <li><a href="faq" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

It works properly. The problem is: if i have one url with call to div like www.site.com/about#team, the menu loose the active highlight.

Can someone please help me to improve this script to works also with the # in pages? Also, can someone tell me if its the best way to do it with jquery? There are a more complete or secure way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`. `location.pathname` will just return the pathname, which wold be everything after the `http://www.site.com` and everything before the `#team`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Bill!!!!!! BTW, is there a better and more complex/secure way to do it?

Comment: I think it's about as easy to read as it's going to get. Why would you want to make it more complex and why would it need to be secure?

Comment: No problem! Hope everything turns out well!